# GCloud terraform export - unknown resource type: google_logging_log_sink

Tags: terraform, gcloud, terraform-provider-gcp

I followed [Google's instructions](https://cloud.google.com/docs/terraform/resource-management/import) to export my GCloud project in a terraform format. I tried using `gcloud alpha` and `gcloud beta` and the result is the same: It creates a resource named `google_logging_log_sink`, for which I can't find documentation in Terraform's [Google Cloud Platform Provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs).

The commands I executed are in the following order, with `+` to show the generated files and folders. They worked the same using `gcloud alpha` and `gcloud beta`, and I omit sensitive data:

```bash
$> gcloud alpha resource-config bulk-export --path=terraform-export --project=PROJECT_ID --resource-format=terraform

+ ./terraform-export/...
```

```bash
$> gcloud beta resource-config terraform generate-import terraform-export

+ ./gcloud-export-modules.tf
+ ./terraform_import_2022MMDD-HH-mm-ss.sh
```

```bash
$> terraform init

+ ./.terraform/…
+ ./terraform.lock.hcl
```

```bash
$> zsh ./terraform_import_2022MMDD-HH-mm-ss.sh # <- the errors are thrown here

+ ./.terraform.tfstate.lock.info
+ ./.terraform.tfstate.backup
```

There are specifically two errors in that script, their commands and messages are the following.

1. `unknown resource type: google_logging_log_sink`:

```bash
$> terraform import module.terraform-export-PROJECTNUMBER-PROJECTNUMBER-Project-LoggingLogSink.google_logging_log_sink.a_required PROJECTNUMBER###_Required

module.terraform-export-PROJECTNUMBER-PROJECTNUMBER-Project-LoggingLogSink.google_logging_log_sink.a_required: Importing from ID "PROJECTNUMBER###_Required"...
╷
│ Error: unknown resource type: google_logging_log_sink
│ 
│ 
╵
```

(I also tried adding a space in `PROJECTNUMBER###_Required` -> `PROJECT_NUMBER ###_Required` and it fails with the same message.)

2. `Cannot import non-existent remote object`:

```bash
$> terraform import module.terraform-export-projects-PROJECTID-IAMServiceAccount.google_service_account.PROJECTID projects/PROJECTID/serviceAccounts/some_service_account@PROJECTID.iam.gserviceaccount.com

module.terraform-export-projects-PROJECTID-IAMServiceAccount.google_service_account.PROJECTID: Importing from ID "projects/PROJECTID/serviceAccounts/some_service_account@PROJECTID.iam.gserviceaccount.com"...
module.terraform-export-projects-PROJECTID-IAMServiceAccount.google_service_account.PROJECTID: Import prepared!
  Prepared google_service_account for import
module.terraform-export-projects-PROJECTID-IAMServiceAccount.google_service_account.PROJECTID: Refreshing state... [id=projects/PROJECTID/serviceAccounts/some_service_account@PROJECTID.iam.gserviceaccount.com]
╷
│ Error: Cannot import non-existent remote object
│ 
│ While attempting to import an existing object to "module.terraform-export-projects-PROJECTID-IAMServiceAccount.google_service_account.PROJECTID", the provider detected that no object exists with the given id. Only
│ pre-existing objects can be imported; check that the id is correct and that it is associated with the provider's configured region or endpoint, or use "terraform apply" to create a new remote object for this resource.
╵
```

Calling `terraform -v` shows the following versions:

```bash
Terraform v1.2.1
on darwin_amd64
 + provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google_v4.22.0
```

- How do I solve these errors?
- Would fixing the
  `google_logging_log_sink` error also allow the second failing
  command to succeed?

I have looked for some documentation of the `google_logging_log_sink` resource but have found none, so don't know if I need to change it for some other resource name. I also think my `terraform` CLI and the google provider versions should be working. I couldn't find the version of the format in which gcloud is exporting the project.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does the `PROJECTNUMBER` get replaced with anything?

Comment: Yes, it is in reality the number of my GCloud project with format "123456781234". In the other hand, `PROJECTID` is a word "my-gcloud-project".

Comment: Ok, I see there is a note for the log sink in the provider documentation: `You must enable the Cloud Resource Manager API`. Is that API enabled in your project?

Comment: Yes, it is enabled. I tried changing it to `google_logging_project_sink` and changed the id to one with the format `projects/PROJECTNUMBER/sinks/_Required`. Does that make sense?

Comment: @EmmanuelB - on first look, using is the `google_logging_project_sink` seem the right thing go far. Anyway I have reported it for further investigation.

Answer (score 3):

As of Jun 2022, there is **no fix**! The [config connector](https://cloud.google.com/docs/terraform/resource-management/export#before_you_begin) that lets you use Google Cloud's Terraform bulk-export tool needs this fix.  In future versions, you can expect this to be fixed.

The simple workaround for now, is to ignore the Terraform Export only for `google_logging_log_sink` resource and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by replacing `google_logging_log_sink` with `google_logging_project_sink` - see https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/logging_project_sink